# how to map dynamic input with entity in watson conversation (Bluemix)

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I am trying to make a chat bot which can answer some of my questions like :-

"i need to know about birds like sparrow, peacock, parrot or i need to know about bird sparrow.".

Birds names would be dynamic entry here and user can ask about any bird name and any list of bird name, all this should be dynamic.

So how would i map single bird name or list, with entity dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

[Watson Assistant has an API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl) that allows to manage (create, delete, update) entities. That could be used to dynamically add bird names as values to an existing entity `bird`. Note that cognitive systems need to be trained to correctly identify patterns, e.g., bird names.

Detected bird names would be flagged in the response object. How do you plan to react to them? You could use that in a dialog and use [dialog actions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions) to look up details for the specific bird or the birds in the list.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i wanted to create all, here in Watson-assistant dialog action itself, right now i am not accessing response object, so suppose i am testing the question  "the examples of laptops are hp, lenovo and dell" then how would i map laptops with name entity and hp,lenevo and dell with list entity, and all this entry user put dynamically.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. What is your entity definition?